# What is the point of being able to use compile-time characteristics of non-captured local variables in a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, capture

I noticed that one is allowed to use compile-time characteristics of variables which were not captured in lambda e.g. call `sizeof`, `decltype` functions, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
void f ()
{
}

int main()
{
  int y = 13;
  auto x = []{ return sizeof (decltype (y));};
  std::cout << x () << '\n';
}
```

As both `g++` and `clang++` compile this program without errors I guess it is allowed by the standard.

It seems a bit misleading to me even though I can't think of any particular malicious case where it will lead to a mistake. But I wonder what are the actual use-cases of this feature?

Comment: More generally, you only need to capture local variables if they're *odr-used*. For example, you may use the value of local `constexpr` variables such as `constexpr int x = 42;`.

Comment: Seems quite reasonable to me, I wouldnt like to have variables I dont access in the capture scope.

Comment: What are the actual use cases of a building brick?

Comment: Both sizeof and decltype don't actually evaluate their expression. They just use the compiler's knowledge to replace the code with the proper value. You could've just put sizeof(y) and it wouldn't have required a capture either

Comment: I once used this for a quick and dirty type erasure: `auto l = new auto([f, t]{ f(t); }); auto e = [](void* el){ auto* pl = static_cast<decltype(l)*>(el); (*pl)(); delete pl; };` The lambda `e` is then convertible to a `void(*)()`, which can be stored alongside `(void*)l`.

Comment: Cfr. 5.3.3/p1 `The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is
either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand` and ODR-used at 3.2/p2 and 3.2/p3 `An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated operand` plus lambda capture 5.1.2/p12.1 and 5.1.2/p12.2. As for "what are the use-cases", it is too broad. It's like asking what's the use case for sizeof itself.

Comment: @MarcoA. Sorry maybe I didn't express the question in the best way possible, the confusing thing to me is why variable name is exposed in lambda scope without capture. Probably the right answer though would be that since it doesn't add anything dangerous, so there was no need to add a special rule for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example where you might use this is if you have a lambda where you want to perform calculations in the same type as `y`, because you will be assigning the result to `y`.

Also, think of it the other way around: what's the benefit of capturing `y` in `[=]{ return x + sizeof (y);}`? There is absolutely no point in doing so, since `y` is not actually used inside the lambda. Capturing `y` would just add completely pointless overhead. Not only that, it might even complicate the inner workings of compilers, since they would no longer be able to simply optimise `y` away, `sizeof(y)` is no longer semantically equivalent to `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: OK, so as far as I understand if you capture variable by reference and it will be gone out of scope later, while you wouldn't add any overhead in this case, you may run into risk of using this variable inside lambda when it's already gone out of scope. So that's probably the right reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in a nested scope (lambda) you need type information without the value. You can always name the type (or template parameter) directly if you have access to it but there is always that urban legend good advice saying that if someday you change the type of the variable you won't have to change it in all the other expressions where you have repeated it.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

class   storage
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  auto    make_getter(T value)
  {
    std::get<decltype(value)>(storage_) = value;

    auto getter = [this]
      {
        return std::get<decltype(value)>(storage_);
      };

    return getter;
  }

private:
  std::tuple<int, char, double>   storage_;
};

int     main(void)
{
  storage       s;

  auto getter = s.make_getter(42);

  std::cout << getter() << std::endl;
}
```

Here you can always use `std::get<T>` instead of `std::get<decltype(value)>`but if someday `make_getter`is not a template anymore and it becomes a normal function overloaded for each type of the tuple than the type of value would change to `int` for example, the advantage here is that `decltype(value)` will always work provided you don't rename the variable.

Anyway i think the utility level of this feature might be more semantic than technical. This behaviour is probably inherited from the old school canonical

```
char *buffer = malloc(42 * sizeof(*buffer));
```

used in the `C` language instead of

```
char *buffer = malloc(42 *sizeof(char));
```

for the same reasons.

Also if the type name is something unbearable that you do not want to alias for some reason you'll go the decltype way which doesn't necessarily means you want the associated value.